# how to add link of my github repo to npm package?

Tags: github, npm

I need to add an link of my [github](http://github.com) repository to my [npm](http://npmjs.com) package. I did not find the solution yet on the [npm](http://npmjs.com) documentation.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You have a field called **repository** in package.json. If not, you can make it yourself. Add the GitHub repository URL there:

```
"repository": {
  "type": "git",
  "url": "https://github.com/your-user/repo-url.git"
},
```

Make sure you specify **git** as type and that the URL is pointing to the actual repository, not an HTML page. So the URL has to end with *.git*. You can copy/paste the URL you find when you click the *Clone or download* button on GitHub.

There is also a field called **homepage** that you can use to point to the repository landing page.

The documentation is [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#repository), by the way.

Comment: Do you really need the `.git` at the end?

Comment: `"repository": "github:user/repo"` see: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#repository

Comment: Is it possible to make the npm point on a subfolder? For example, I have `"url"` pointing on repo itself, plus I have a `"directory"` field that points on the package itself inside the repo. But npm still points on the root repo instead of adding the directory to the link.

Comment: @Alendorff it seems to be possible: the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#repository) says that "If the package.json for your package is not in the root directory (for example if it is part of a monorepo), you can specify the directory in which it lives" using the `directory` property of `repository` object.